# Open Graph URL values for facebook-provided video

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to setup the open graph tags for Facebook video so that the user can play the video from within Facebook:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10153231379946729" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />

<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />
```

When I include the Flash URL, after clicking the play button I get a text link to download the video.

If I remove the Flash URL entirely and click the play button, a video player appears but it errors out with the message `undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.` in the console.

Anyone know the correct URLs to use for `content` for both Flash and MP4?

Comment: Look the video id up via API, the `source` field holds the URL to the video file itself. (Not sure though if they will let you use that in OG meta tags – for og:image it says that you can’t use images from their CDN, so I expect it might be similar with videos.)